# Is f holomorph on the $B \left( a, \dfrac{R}{e} \right) $?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

E and F be a Banach spaces. Let U be an open subset of E. A mapping $f :U \longrightarrow F$ is said to be holomorphic if for each $a \in U $ there exist a ball $ B(a,r) \subset U $ and a sequence of polynomials $P_m \in \mathcal{P}( ^m E, F) $ such that $f(x)= \sum _{ m=0} ^\infty P_m (x-a) $ uniformly for $x \in B(a,r). $

Let $\sum _{ m=0} ^\infty P_m (x-a) $ be a power serie from E to F which is every $P_m$ is continuous and radius of convergence R >0. $f : B(a,R) \longrightarrow $ F, let  $f(x) := \sum _{ m=0} ^\infty P_m (x-a) $.

Here are my questions; How can I show that f is holomorph on $B \left( a, \dfrac{R}{e} \right) $ and also can we show that f is holomorph on $B(a,r)$ ?

Comment: I don't understand the questions. Above all, what is your definition of "radius of convergence R"? and doesn't it answer your question(s)?

Comment: @AnneBauval  The radius of convergence of the power series
is the supremum of all  $r \geq 0 $ such that the series converges
uniformly on the closed ball B[a,r] and also we know that from Cauchy- Hadamad formula $\dfrac{1}{R} = \limsup _{m \to \infty } || P_m || ^{1/m }.$